# Referencing products in blog post?

Tags: shopify

I'm looking at putting together a store for a client and trying to decide on what platform to use.

One piece of functionality they want to be able to have is the ability to reference products in their blog posts and then have users add all of these products to their checkout in one click.

Would something like this be possible in Shopify?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Shopify Buy Button example [here](http://www.shopify.com/buy-button), and the documentation for it is [here](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/buy-button).

It basically allows you to embed a one-click add-to-cart and checkout solution on any page, such as a blog post.

I'm not sure, however, if it will be possible to incorporate multiple products into a buy button as you hint at in your question.

Comment: It does indeed! We support multiple products through collections as well: https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/buy-button/create-buy-button#create-collection

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Can you mark this answer as correct, @samturner?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct and you can have multiple products with buy button. The buy button creates an embed code that you can cut and paste in your Shopify blog or any other site such as a Wordpress site or an affiliates site. Here is an example of a [Shopify blog with multiple buy buttons](http://www.teramasu.com/blogs/news/17896609-3-stunning-ways-to-dress-country-chic-with-helens-heart-bling-boots).